# How to order columns in histogram with Plotly and cufflinks

Tags: python, plotly, cufflinks

Currently, with the following code, I get two histograms without ordered columns and the order in both are different. How can I alter it using the structure already in use? I have formatted a full presentation using the same library and wish not to change it

```
df_trans = data.pivot(columns='Response', values= 'Education')
df_trans.iplot(sortbars = True, shared_yaxis = True,subplots = True, kind='histogram',histnorm = 'probability',xTitle='Stocks',
               yTitle='Returns Distribution',title='Cufflinks - Box Plot')
```

Sample table

```
  Response  Education
0   1   Graduation
1   0   Graduation
2   0   Graduation
3   0   Graduation
4   0   PhD
5   0   Master
6   0   Graduation
7   0   PhD
8   1   PhD
9   0   PhD
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)? And please code as text not pic.

Comment: It is done rpanai

Comment: Do you mind to check your data? It's not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, now it is correct

Comment: Hi Flávio your question is not reproducible yet. Do you mind to double check? Having a reproducible question increase the chance to get one or more answer very quickly.